# The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows'

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, .net-4.5.2

I need to select json file.

```
public void LoadChartData()
{
   var ofDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog { Filter = @"json (*.json)|*.json" };
   if (ofDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
   { }
}
```

Unfortunately compilation of this code returns error (twice, for each `System.Windows.Forms` ):

```
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

How to handle with this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Include the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly in your project (as the error message suggested).

Go to your *Solution Explorer*, right click your project. Then click *Add Reference*. Choose *System.Windows.Forms* and hit *OK*.